# What is INL and DNL value for this case

Tags: adc

i am trying to recreate the calculation for INL and DNL
for n=100
$$S_{avg}=0.091$$
$$INL=\frac{(V_{actual}-V_{uniform})}{S_{avg}}=\frac{(0.33-0.35)}{0.091}=-0.21$$
$$DNL=\frac{(V_{actual_{100}}-V_{actual_{011}})}{S_{avg}} -1=\frac{(0.33-0.17)}{0.091} -1=0.75$$
both of them doesnt match the INL and DNL results in the table for 100 .
Where did i go wrong?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: done editing in latex

Comment: Your question does not make much sense to me without any context. What is INL, DNL, Savg? Where did you find the formulas and the table?